# Data normalization for recommender system

Tags: machine-learning, standardization, recommender-system

Does anyone know whether it's a good idea to standardize your data by replacing it with the percentile which it occupies in a distribution? Instead of substracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation.

Say for variable $X$, replace each $X_i$ with the percentile it occupies in the distribution of $X$, instead of replacing it with $(X_i-\bar{X})/\text{sd}(X)$.

It's for a recommender system. I want to translate some data I have into an implicit $0-100$ rating.

Comment: It's for a recommender system. I want to translate some data I have into an implicit 0-100 rating.

Comment: Why not go for $100 \times \frac{x-\min(x)}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$? See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345569/normalize-over-range-with-min-excluded/ or idem https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/342327

Comment: What advantages does it holds over using percentiles? What I don't like of this approach is that it can be screwed up by the shape of the distribution. Say I have lots of users with Xi close to 99, and a few users with low Xi, say around 20. Then most of my users will be clustered around high values of the new feature. What I like of percentiles is that it's unambiguous in that 99 means top 1%, even if users in the 98 percentiles are close to them in terms of Xi value.

Comment: This method is in use, but whether it's a "good idea" or not depends on what it's used for.  Please edit your post to provide that information.

Comment: Thanks -- but could you explain what this "implicit 0 - 100 rating" would be for and how you plan to use it?  Otherwise, about all we can tell you is yes, your procedure will produce numbers between 0 and 100--but we have no information to determine whether it's any good or makes any sense.

Comment: The advantages over the percentile method: (1) It is invertible given $\min$ and $\max$. (2) It preserves the shape of the distribution. (3) The effect on estimated parameters is often predictable and invertible. 

In short: you lose less information.

Comment: I have the average spending of users on X1,X2,...,Xn items (averaged over the average period of purchase of the items).

I like the percentile approach because being in the top 1% of Xi consumers is represented as a 99 rating, while the median consumer would rate it as 50, and someone who hasn't consumed it yet would rate it as 0.

Comment: Thanks Jim, you're right. What bothers me about translating into percentiles is that I (obviously) end up with a uniform distribution (after excluding people with 0 spending).

Comment: I'd end up with a matrix of user/items ratings in which the rating is the percentile each user occupies in their spending on any given item. Then I want to run ALS for matrix factorization on these ratings (treating the 0s as missing values).